# iOS background fetch before termination

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a situation where I must call a web service before app termination but not when enters the background, because this should be done only once which when the app get terminated.

I tried the background execution thing but I believe it won't work once the app get terminated but only if the app in the background.

Here is my latest try inside `applicationWillTerminate:`

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
        // Call web service here 
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask =UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
```

Comment: I have a hard time seeing any good use case for this pattern. Can you provide details on why this is the way you want it to do? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Is your web service asynchronous?  If so then you may be calling `endBackgroundTask` before it has completed. Also be aware that `applocationWillTerminate` isn't always called

Comment: @Eiko The case is I want to make the user offline automatically if the app get terminated

Comment: How are you connected to the server? If there was an open socket, the server should notice anyway. I still don't see the point here - for the user an app running in background and a terminated app look *exactly* the same, and the user can't chose between those states. So it should feel and behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, and honestly, why would you?

This is an ill-posed problem anyway. What should happen if the battery dies? What if the app crashes? What if the app goes to background and then the OS terminates it when memory pressure increases? What if you lose internet access and the app is terminated?

The closest thing you can do is to implement some sort of heartbeat service which your app regularly pings. If the pinging stops, your app has either terminated or network connectivity was lost.